Only last entry of hashmap get added to nested hashmap and returned
HashMap<String,String> details=new HashMap<>();
switch(value){
    case "approved":
        if(rs!=null) {
            
            int i = 1;
            while(rs.next()) {                          
                String NO = rs.getString("NO");
                String CLASS = rs.getString("CLASS");
                String CLASS_DESC = rs.getString("CLASS_DESC");

                details.put("NO", NO);
                details.put("CLASS", CLASS);
                details.put("CLASS_DESC", CLASS_DESC);
                                        
                System.out.println(details);
                HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> detailsall = new HashMap<>();
                detailsall.put(i,details);
                i++;
                System.out.println(detailsall);
            }
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> detailsallmap : detailsall.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(detailsallmap.getKey() + " = "+ detailsallmap.getValue());
            }
        }else {
            details=null;
        }
        break;            
}

Iterating over each entry of resultset and add to hashmap and that hashmap adding as nested map.
But its adding as only last entry to nested hashmap.

details is main hashmap where adding resultset entries
detailsall is nestedmap where adding details hashmap entries


Why make the whole text bold? makes reading harder and actually does not emphasize anything (your problem: details should be initialized [and declared] inside the while loop; otherwise code will be adding the same instance to detailsall)

The inner maps would be better as a custom class with 3 fields.  The outer map would be better as an ArrayList.  Better in the sense of 1) faster, 2) uses less space and 3) more idiomatic Java.

It seems to me that the detailsall map should be defined once, and the details map should be created on each iteration, instead of the reverse you're doing now. That is, currently you're overwriting the same map assigned to details on each iteration, and adding it to a detailsall that you create (and throw away) on each iteration. The code as shown shouldn't even compile, because the for loop outside the while loop shouldn't be able to reference detailsall.

@MarkRotteveel want to store each resultset to Hashmap and return it as one.

Something is wrong with the code you've shown - detailsall is a local variable and is referenced outside the loop, so it just looks like you've declared another field detailsall in global scope - or as Mark Rotteveel points out, this code would not compile.

@Shr My point is that is not what your code is actually doing.

You'll need to increment your counter.
detailsall.put(i++,details);

Also, you'll need to move the line that creates details HashMap inside the while loop.

Still same issue

You'll also have to move the line that creates details HashMap inside the while loop.

@user85421 I've already updated it.
